# Symfony2: Create table from command line

Tags: symfony, command-line, create-table

I am new to symfony2.

Is it possible to create table (fields with relevant data types) from command line without creating entity first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="BundleName:EntityName" --fields="name:string(255)"
```

Comment: Can you please also provide the URL where all supported data types are given that can be used with --fields option?

Comment: @neeraj, see here http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#book-doctrine-field-types